# Git-svn for repo with independent subprojects

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to use git-svn for an svn project that has multiple sub-projects, each with its own independent trunk/branches/tags structure:

```
PROJECT
    SubprojectA
        branches
        tags
        trunk
    SubprojectB
        branches
        tags
        trunk
```

Is it possible to still support branches and tags with git-svn? I don't need it all checked out in one repo, if that's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, branches and tags should work fine as long as you split it into two git repos, one for each project. Pass the `-s` (`--stdlayout`) flag to `git-svn` and clone each one with the svn URL of the directory just above "trunk, tags, branches".